# Exit link tracking with timestamped logs on 3rd party content

Tags: links, tracking, logging, url-shorteners

I want to track clicks on exit links, that are placed in 3rd party content, for example on Twitter. I also need the timestamps of the clicks.

Google Analytics can't be embedded in 3rd party content.

Another solution is to use a URL shortener like bit.ly. However, bit.ly or goo.gl don't log the time of the click with any better granularity than a full day.

su.pr shows the time for the past day in its analytics graph. The analytics download only includes the day, not the time.

cli.gs [was touted](http://www.toprankblog.com/2009/01/11-best-url-shortening-services-vote-your-favorite/) as having the most detailed analytics, yet it doesn't show the time either, and forces the user through a preview page.

Hootsuite/ow.ly doesn't let you drill into analytics intraday.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to track clicks on exit links [...] Google Analytics can't be
>   embedded in 3rd party content.

It is true that your Google Analytics profile cannot be used to track traffic or activity on *other peoples'* sites, however, if you are only concerned with tracking when users *on your site* click exit links *on your site*, Google Analytics is perfectly sufficient to track the users who have Javascript enabled.

See [How do I manually track clicks on outbound links?](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527) at the Google Analytics documentation for code snippets and instructions.